# Find the directrix of the parabola with equation $y=-0.5x^2+2x+2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

> Find the directrix of the parabola with equation
>   $$y=-0.5x^2+2x+2$$

I did this:

$$a=-0.5, b = 2, c = 2$$

Formula for the directrix is:

$$y=-1/(4a)$$

$$y=-1/(4\cdot(-0.5))=3.5$$

This is not right:

[image]

What went wrong? What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: The right formula is $y=-1/(4a)+y_0$, where $y_0$ is the ordinate of the vertex.

Comment: In addition, you miscomputed $-1/(4a)$.

Comment: @Aretino How did you derive that formula? Is that always the one to use if I want to find the directrix of a parabola. By the way it works now when I use the formula you denoted.

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#As_a_graph_of_a_function

Answer (score 1):

Complete the square $$\begin{aligned} y&=-0.5x^2+2x+2\\ &=-0.5(x^2-4x)+2\\ &=-0.5(x^2-4x+4-4)+2\\ &=-0.5[(x-2)^2-4]+2\\&=-0.5(x-2)^2+4\end{aligned}$$
or equivalently $$y-4=-0.5(x-2)^2.$$
The directrix is given by $$y-4=-\frac{1}{4a}\quad \text{with}\; a=-0.5$$
or $$y=4+\frac{1}{2}$$